# Adding an object to a NSArray

Tags: xcode, nsarray

```
NSString* title = [rescue objectForKey:@"title"];
NSString* name = [rescue objectForKey:@"name"];


NSMutableArray* listBossF = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Hello %@ %@  I've just arrived"[title, name] ,
                                   @"Hello  %@ %@everything is fine",
                                   @"Hello  %@ %@ are there any news back at the office?",
                                   @"Hello ( %@ %@ i arrived at the hotel" ,
                                   @"Hello %@ %@ I've just arrived at the airport", nil];
```

Hello im very new to xcode and in fact to programming in general, i've been trying for quite a while to add an object to a specific part of the array (thats why i cant used componentsJoinedByString) but i've had a lot of trouble doing so, the way i'd normally do can anyone tell me what i've been doing wrong? And if i can't add objects to a specific part of an array can anyone possibly give me a suggestion of what i should try? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an object to a specific part of an array like so:

```
[array insertObject:@"Hello" atIndex:1]; // After first object in array
```

Comment: Yes, array's start at "0" (zero) so inserting at index "1" would insert an object after the first object. (just wanted to clarify why Brayden used "1" as opposed to "2" since you mentioned you were new to programming.